# File.Copy fails when copying a DLL that is not in use

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, file-io, copy

I've built a winforms app (C#) that will take a list of file paths, and copy those files (from a different VS solution) to a new location (In a folder the user specifies) in the same directory structure they currently exist on local file system.

I use the Path class, Directory class etc and everything works wonderfully...except when it reaches a file path that points to a DLL.

The DLLs I am trying to copy are a part of the other solution, and that solution is not currently open.

I have tried restarting computer to make sure visual studio isn't somehow hooking into that DLL even after the solution is closed.

The DLL in question can be copied by regular manual means (i.e. copy and paste shortcut).

So short of creating a batch file in the program, and running xcopy on that DLL path, I don't know of a way to get this to work.

From what I have found from google searches (which isn't much on this particular situation), File.Copy() should work..

Any help would be wonderful, even if it is a link to a duplicate question I may have over looked.

Thanks!

-The error message is: The process cannot access the file [insert file path] because it is being used by another process (The path is definitely correct also)

-Just downloaded and tried to search for the DLL name with Process Explorer.. I also ran a similar exe from command prompt to no avail. It claims nothing is using it. That's why I am utterly baffled by this. Also, I just checked the permissions and everything looks great (i.e. Full Control, owner effective permissions)

-It does not handle open files. It basically build the correct src and dest paths and does a File.Copy() on those. How would I go about handling open files? I'm sure I could figure out if it was open, but what would I do it it were open?

Comment: You can download Process Explorer from Microsoft and check what program uses it, and alternatively close the handle if you like. For some reason someone locks it, but noone except you can tell us what application it is.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to copy the files? It could be that your method doesn't account for open files.

Comment: Does it say which file is in use by another process? Obviously this point is moot if the destination file does not exist . . . Have you placed a breakpoint just before the `File.Copy` and checked Process  Explorer to be sure that nothing already has the source or destination open? Are you sure that the source and destination aren't pointing to the same file? I know that `File.Copy` will copy DLL files because I've used it for that. There must be a problem in your code.

Comment: [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) is also a nice tool for detecting and killing file handles

Answer (score 2):

It is not complaining about the file you're trying to copy, it is complaining about the file that you're trying to overwrite with the copy.  Lots of candidates for that, virus scanners always get very excited about new DLLs, for example.  Or it is loaded into a process, the typical failure mode for trying to implement your own auto-updater.

You can rename the target file to make your copy succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in vista or win7? If so, Check your 'User Account Control Settings'.  Sometimes this can interfere with .NET security options and prevent file operations that would otherwise work.

Answer (score 1):

As well as Process Explorer, I would use Process Monitor also from Microsoft so you can see what is happening at the point of failure and allows you to see if anything else is accessing the dll.

Possible culprits are

1. the program you are running,
2. your antivirus package
3. a virus.

If the path it is complaining about is the destination path, then is is possible that the path is too long?

Also, when using Process Explorer, make sure you have enabled the option to show details for all processes and not just your own.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue as well. I tried copying a .DLL from an FTP server to a local directory (replacing the existing one) and for the life of me I could not get it to work. Keeps giving me an 'Access Denied code: 5' Error.

I then realized that the .DLL on the FTP server was not marked as hidden while the .DLL I was trying to replace was marked as hidden.

Once I changed the local one to also be visible. I had no more issues.

So my solution is:
Make sure both files are visible.

Hope this helps someone